# Where can I find the Bragg Curves for Heavy Particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation

The Bragg Curves are graphs plotting the energy loss of ionizing radiation (KeV/μm usually) on the y-axis during its travel through matter (distance travelled usually in cm) on the x-axis.

I can't seem to find studies in my internet/textbook/encyclopedia searches graphing the Braggs Curves for Helium Nucleii and/or Osmium +8.

Where in the internet can I find studies graphing the Bragg Curves for Protons, Helium Nuclei (α-particles), Carbon Ions and Osmium Ions; could you please give me the URLs for such studies?

Comment: SRIM (aka TRIM) can provide them for you. Initial charge state has no particular impact unless the energy is very low. By the way, why the interest in Osmium as an ion? Its a pretty toxic thing to want to have in an ion source.

Comment: @JonCuster https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4192/where-is-a-question-on-radiobiology-and-dosimetry-going-to-best-be-answered the question is motivated by my intellectual curiosity and my cancer. Hopefully I would find a heavy particle that had a point mass Bragg Curve (it would have 0 energy loss in all but one point) and furthermore the Radiation Oncologist could manipulate at what depth the energy loss would happen (the energy would be deposited). Sparing everything else the damage (I am ignoring the damage done from free radicals and only considering SSBs and DSBs).

Comment: Protons are by far the best for nearly single-depth energy deposition. But that energy is nuclear energy stopping, not electronic stopping. Which is actually preferable for really destroying stuff (see proton beam therapy).

Comment: @JonCuster https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fonc.2020.00082/full   https://www.frontiersin.org/files/Articles/497476/fonc-10-00082-HTML/image_m/fonc-10-00082-g001.jpg It seems that Carbon Ion is closer to single-depth energy deposition. Fragmentation seems problematic though,

Comment: @JonCuster Why do you affirm that protons are by far the best for nearly single-depth energy deposition? Seeing the Bragg Curves of Protons and Carbon-Ions the Bragg Peak is roughly the same but much sharper with Carbon-Ions. I guess if we took the definite integral around a couple of μms of the Bragg Peak and Divided by the Energy of the Particles, this Ratio would be much higher for Carbon-Ions (a point mass would have a ratio of 1). What worries me with Carbon-Ions is the tail (probably due to fragmentation). I want to keep my sharp peak but do away will the tail in my alternative particle.